# Proving symmetry for complex inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have an operation like:

$$\langle p(x),g(x)\rangle = \int_0^2p(x)g(x)$$

We have to prove symmetry, so I guess it would be like this:

$$\int_0^2p(x)g(x) = \int_0^2 \overline g(x)\overline p(x)$$

Simplifies to:

$$\int_0^2 p(x)g(x) = \int_0^2\overline p(x)\overline g(x)$$

From there, I'm not sure how to prove the rest.

Comment: Are $p$, $g$ both complex-valued functions?

Comment: Yes, they can contain {1,i,x}

Comment: Do you want to show $\langle p(x), g(x)\rangle = \langle g(x), p(x)\rangle $?

Comment: I want to prove the operation in the first line is symmetric.

Comment: For a complex inner product, one has $\langle x,y \rangle = \overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user83039: If that is what you want to show, then probably you need to check again your definition. Does it has a bar over $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that symmetry, Just to show that $\langle p(x),g(x)\rangle =\langle g(x),p(x)\rangle $.

Does $$\langle p(x),g(x)\rangle = \int_0^2p(x)g(x)=\int_0^2g(x)p(x)=\langle g(x),p(x)\rangle $$ hold?

Comment: I thought the process was $<f,g> = \overline{<g,f>}$ like here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217486/prove-that-a-function-is-an-inner-product