# Prove that $\langle p,q\rangle:=\int_{0}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx$ is a dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

> Let $p,q\in\mathbb{R}_2[X]$ and define $\langle p,q\rangle:=\int_{0}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx$. Show that $\langle \, , \,\rangle$ is a dot product on $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$.

My problem is showing that $\langle \, , \,\rangle$ is positive definite, since, as far as I understand it, one can define $p:=-8X, q:=2X$ and in that case $\langle \, , \,\rangle$ would be negative, wouldn't it?

Comment: Look up the definition of an inner product. Positive definiteness requires that $\langle p,p\rangle > 0$ for $ p \ne 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217486/prove-that-a-function-is-an-inner-product

Comment: @MartinR Thank you but in my example we have that $p\neq 0$ and still $\langle p,q \rangle<0$, isn't it?

Comment: Nothing wrong with orthogonal elements that are distinct. We want a vector to be not orthogonal to *itself*.

Comment: @user: Read the definition again. It's $\langle p,p\rangle > 0$, not $\langle p,q\rangle > 0$.

Comment: @MartinR Ohhh, that's why, I misread it as $p,q$ the whole time, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Positive definite is about $\langle p, p \rangle$ being $>0$ for $p\neq 0$. The dot product can very well be negative for some pairs, and will be as $\langle p, -q \rangle = -\langle p, q \rangle$, so if one is positive the other is negative.

Lemma to use: if $\int_0^1 g(x) dx = 0$ and $g \ge 0$ and $g$ continuous, then $g \equiv0$.

Comment: Thank you but in my example $p\neq 0$ and the dot product is still negative, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user have you computed $\langle p, p \rangle$ for your $p$? That is the integral of $64X^2$..

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, you can see from the above comments what my real problem was.