# Let $A,B\in M_n (\mathbb R), \lambda\in \sigma(B), \alpha \in \sigma (B)$ and $<x,y>$ be inner product show $<Ax+By,x>=\lambda||x||^2+\alpha<x,y>$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, problem-solving

**Let $A,B\in M_n (\mathbb R), \lambda\in \sigma (A), \alpha \in \sigma (B)$ and $<x,y>$ be inner product show $<Ax+By,x>=\lambda||x||^2+\alpha<x,y>$ where $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ are eigenvectors associated with $\lambda,\alpha$ respectively**

I'm really confused I'm not sure what this problem means when they say $\lambda\in \sigma(B), \alpha \in (B)$ - what is sigma B?

In [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217486/prove-that-a-function-is-an-inner-product) here the solution checked the three conditions and I thought that was I was supposed to do?

Comment: What in fact is $(B)$?

Comment: YOu seem to use some notation that isn't that standard...and you don't explain. $\;\sigma(B)\;$ seems to be the set of all eigenvalues of $\;B\;$ ,and $\;\alpha\in (B)\;$ seems a rahter wierd way to denote... **what**?

Comment: @RobertLewis fixed the typo

Comment: I still can't see what $(B)$ means.

Comment: You can use `\langle x, y \rangle` to get $\langle x, y \rangle$. Those also play nice with the `\left` and `\right` commands.

Comment: $\sigma(\cdot)$ is a popular notation for spectrum (i.e. the set of all eigenvalues) of a matrix.

Comment: does anyone know how to actually go about solving this though now that I know its a spectrum?